# Python: Delete folders based on ticket status

Tags: python, windows, selenium, jira

I'm trying to build a script in python that will automatically delete folders from a shared network location based on their Resolution in JIRA.

All of the folder names use the following basename "PROJECT-11111" and that is basically the ticket ID in jira (eg: jira.host.com\browse\PROJECT-11111).

What I'm struggling with, and this may be easy but I'm pretty new to python and programming in general, is that in the shared network location there are folders that don't necessarily use the format mentioned above and I want to filter those out as I'd like to call the base jira URL + the folder name in order to access the ticket directly.

After that, if the resolution of the ticket is resolved I will need that certain folder to be deleted.

I know that this can be done easier and faster-using REST API, but I'd like to keep it easy in the beginning.

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's consider you have a file repository, which UNC path is `\\jira.host.com\browse`.
This directory contains a folder for each ticket.

To remove the a ticket folder, you can write this kind of function:

```py
import pathlib
import shutil

# WORK_DIR is the UNC path to your file repository
WORK_DIR = pathlib.Path(r"\\jira.host.com\browse")


def remove_folder(ticket_id: str) -> None:
    """ Remove the ticket folder located in the repository """
    ticket_path = WORK_DIR.joinpath(f"PROJECT-{ticket_id}")
    if ticket_path.exists():
        print(f"removing '{ticket_path}'...")
        shutil.rmtree(ticket_path, ignore_errors=True)
    else:
        print(f"'{ticket_path}' already removed.")
```

Then, you can call the `remove_folder` function given the ticket ID.

```py
remove_folder("11111")
```